# How to convert Future[String] to String scala?

Tags: scala

I have a function which takes a String parametr `def externalServerError(response: String)` and i cant send my Future[String] parametr
i tryed to change a function to `def externalServerError(response: Future[String])` but it gives an error, because inside i use class from library `ServerErrorRequestException` which expected Option[String]. Here is full code:

```
 def externalServerError(response: String): ErrorInfo = {
    val apiException = ServerErrorRequestException(
      message = Some(response)
    )
    apiExceptionToErrorInfo(apiException)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could switch entirely to `async`:

```
def externalServerError(response: Future[String]): Future[ErrorInfo] = {
    response.map(str =>
       apiExceptionToErrorInfo(
          ServerErrorRequestException(
            message = Some(str)
         )
       )
    )
  } 
}
```

Or use Await (**which considered bad style!**)

```
def externalServerError(response: Future[String]): Future[ErrorInfo] = {
    val str = Await.result(response, 1.second)
    apiExceptionToErrorInfo(
       ServerErrorRequestException(
         message = Some(str)
       )
    )
  } 
}
```